# OS X: Self Packaged Kivy-Application does not work

Tags: python, macos, kivy, packaging

I wanted to put myself a bit into Python GUI programming and found Kivy, a really cool Framework, Cross-Platform and open source.

Before I started to put my console-based python script into Kivy, I wanted to test if I can make the program self running without the need to install Kivy or other packages to the system. I started with OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite and the simple "Hello World" usage example provided on the homepage.

There is a guide on the webpage [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-macosx.html#build-the-spec-and-create-a-dmg) which I followed but when it says "That’s it, your self contained package is ready to be deployed! when you double click this app you can see your app run." it just does nothing. No window opens, no message comes up. system.log just says "Kivy[11273]: App did finish launching".

I'm using the newest Kivy package from kivy.org (1.9.0-rev3), symlinks have been created.

Maybe it's my fault: In the guide it says "Now all you need to do is to include your compiled app into the Kivy.app". What's meant with "compiled" app? How do I compile my .py-script before I call the package-app.sh script?

I'm happy with any answer!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?  If so please answer your own question.  I am hoping to package for 10.10 as well.

Comment: I am sorry, I have not tried it again, yet. As the application I am developing now will only run on linux there is no need for a working packed OSX-Version. Nevertheless, I am interested in the answer for future programs.

Answer (score 0):

I used the first method described on that page and experienced the same issue.  Looking inside the .app (right click >> show package contents) it seems Kivy doesn't automatically package external libraries.

After I manually copied the required external libraries I was importing, my app opened without issue.

I copied the libraries from my python directory into:
Contents >> Resources >> venv >> lib >> python2.7 >> site-packages

The python2.7 folder will depend on the version you're using.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, your solution didn't work for me. I tried to copy all the py and all the other files from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7 to the directory inside the application but nothing happened when I double-clicked the app file.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have tried ProGirlXOXO suggestion, but it didn't work.

I noticed that the original script of touchtracer app is the one at location Contents/MacOS, so I simply placed all my external resources into this directory and it worked like a charm.